# MS Graph filtering by companyName doesn't work

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have two similar fragments:

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select("id")
    .Filter("department eq 'Department'")
    .GetAsync();
```

and

```
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request()
    .Select("id")
    .Filter("companyName eq 'CompanyName'")
    .GetAsync();
```

The first fragment works correctly; the second fragment doesn't work at all.

I have success with direct request via HTTP GET

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?ConsistencyLevel=eventual&$count=true&$filter=companyName eq 'Company'
```

So now I have a question: how I can do it with MSGraph API in C#?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what "doesn't work at all." means? Do you get an exception, wrong results, no results or a horse back?

Comment: I understand that Microsoft, as always, has implemented something through one interesting place, but the task at work has been set and it must be somehow realized. It cannot be that there is a filter for one field, but not for the other, especially since companyName is of higher priority than the department. So, I'm looking for solution for this case.

Comment: I can confirm that this returns `BadRequest` in Graph Explorer for `companyName eq...` and also for `../users?$filter=companyName ne null`, although this is given as an example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter),

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've updated my post. Now doesn't clear how it can be reproduced via MS Graph API in C#.

Comment: I also tried it and trying to filter on companyName always returns some kind of error message. As @KekuSemau already mentioned it is explicitly used as an example query within the documentation, this seems to be a bug and you should open a support request at Microsoft and referencing the mentioned documentation and this question.

Answer (score 0):

To add $count=true to your query you should use [QueryOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.queryoption?view=graph-core-dotnet)

```
var options = new List<QueryOption>();
options.Add(new QueryOption("$count", "true"));
IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await graphServiceClient.Users
    .Request(options)
    .Select("id")
    .Filter("companyName eq 'CompanyName'")
    .GetAsync();
```

[Advanced query capabilities on Azure AD directory objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries)

[Query parameters to customize query](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/main/concepts/query-parameters.md)